# how to get turborepo to run the 'deploy' command in every application folder that I have?

Tags: github-actions, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

I have two applications nested in my /apps folder with the latest version of turborepo on a brand new project created this week.

I have created a 'deploy' command in the package.json of both applications and running "pnpm run deploy" works locally, however, during this step only 1 workspace seems to be detected and work during the github action.

My command in the root package.json:

```json
    "deploy": " turbo run deploy --parallel",
```

turbo.json:

```json
{
    "pipeline": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"],
            "outputs": ["dist/**"]
        },
        "deploy": {
            "cache": false
        },
        "lint": {
            "outputs": []
        },
        "dev": {
            "cache": false
        }
    }
}
```

Versions:

```json
    "turbo": "1.3.1"
    "packageManager": "pnpm@7.4.1"
```

Locally: [image]

But then in my github action:

[image]

I'm running ubuntu latest in my action and windows 10 on my machine.

The build step works in CI for both repositories, so this is a rather odd one.

Is there any way I can force that command to run?

I have also created a [github issue in the turborepo repository on github.](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/issues/1484)